# How to replace each preceding whitespace with &nbsp;?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find a regex to replace **each** preceding whitespace of a string with "& nbsp;". Unfortunately I only find expressions that replace all whitespaces together.

Is there a regex for doing this?

```js
var str = "   test !";
console.log(str.replace(/(^\s+)(?=\b)/g, '&nbsp;'));
// replaces all whitespaces with &nbsp;
```

Comment: Maybe `str.replace(/\s/gy, '&nbsp;')`?

Comment: you existing code does *exactly* what you described.. replaces all leading spaces with a non breaking space.. what is the problem?

Comment: @Occam'sRazor **each** vs **all**

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you should post as answer

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes that works indeed, thank you!

Comment: Could you explain, why it only replaces at the beginning of the string? I would have expected to also replace in the middle, eg. "  test  !", that the whitespace before "!" also gets replaces (which is not the case). 

Can you post it as official answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. `str.replace(/ /gy, "&nbsp;")`

```js
var str = "   test !";
console.log(str.replace(/ /gy, "&nbsp;"));
```